# break occurs some where when using break point while running exucatble with gdb

Tags: c, gdb

I have an executable need to be debugged. I have put breakpoint at line 1653 of my source file. The lines 1653 to 1658 contains some declarations. Now I started running the program. The breaking is not occuring at line 1653. Instead it is occuring at line 1659.
can some one please tell me why and how to resolve it.

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: Did you turn optimisation on for compilation?

Answer (score 2):

Your code is probably not built for debugging. If it's compiled with optimizations on, it's possible that the source code lines no longer correspond to anything in the generated code.

Build it without any optimization, and with as much debugging information as possible enabled. How to do this depends on the compiler.

If you can't re-compile the executable, you're going to have to go with what you have.

Answer (score 1):

As *unwind* suggests this may be because your program was built with optimization, but it can also happen with an unoptimized build.  The compiler includes a **line table** in the debug information and the line table tells the debugger what source lines resulted in code being generated.  For instance,

```
15 puts ("This probably resulted in some code being generated.");
16 
17 const int arrsize = 32;  // code generated?  Maybe, maybe not at -O0.
18 char buf[arrsize];       // code generated?  Unlikely.
19
20 // Now we'll start our real work...
21 
22 puts ("This probably resulted in some code being generated.");
```

A breakpoint on line 15 or 22 will probably do what you'd expect.  But it's entire possible that the lines 16 through 21 resulted in no code being generated so as far as the debugger is concerned, these lines don't exist.  If you put a breakpoint on line 18, the debugger will look for the next source line after 18 that has some code generated, and put the breakpoint there.

As *unwind* says, this problem is exacerbated dramatically as soon as optimization is involved by the compiler because source lines may be rearranged in ways you didn't expect or elided altogether (even source lines that seem like would surely result in some code being generated..).  The best way to debug optimized code is to have a mixed source & assembly display and know enough assembly language to follow along as you step through your program IMO.